# Mongo .updateMany() returns TypeError: Property 'updateMany' of object is not a function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following documents in a `users` collection:

Document 1:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5934fd84d6ba4c241259bed1"
    },
    "first_name": "Joe",
    "last_name": "Smith",
    "username": "jsmith",
    "email": "jsmith@gmail.com",
    "password": "$2a$10$eyIbahYKETTtP.i6WlyYd.QeqGNWswW1y/H/aOWw8euFDmWz.wwH2",
    "gender": "male",
    "messages": [
        {
            "$oid": "5937a1118ca79a02a6d10b11"
        }
    ],
    "__v": 16
}
```

Document 2:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5934fe100b557624207db665"
    },
    "first_name": "Sarah",
    "last_name": "Smith",
    "username": "tsmith",
    "email": "tsmith@gmail.com",
    "password": "$2a$10$hfPXLRU4wu2i0/HiVCXO5e2k4ORTsJGZhJ63OpU9OsfTz7JJYRnDS",
    "gender": "female",
    "messages": [
        {
            "$oid": "5937a1118ca79a02a6d10b11"
        }
    ],
    "__v": 25
}
```

How do I iterate through the entire collection, and delete the `messages` array (keep the `messages` key, but with an empty array)?  This collection only has 2 documents, but I want to do it with as many documents as needed.

The resulting document should look like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5934fd84d6ba4c241259bed1"
    },
    "first_name": "Joe",
    "last_name": "Smith",
    "username": "jsmith",
    "email": "jsmith@gmail.com",
    "password": "$2a$10$eyIbahYKETTtP.i6WlyYd.QeqGNWswW1y/H/aOWw8euFDmWz.wwH2",
    "gender": "male",
    "messages": [],
    "__v": 16
}
```

I tried doing this with `db.users.updateMany({}, { $set: { "messages": []}})`, but I'm getting an error: `E QUERY TypeError: Property 'updateMany' of object my_match.users is not a function`.  I'm not passing in a `<filter>` parameter to `updateMany()` because I want to update all documents in the collection per the [mongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/): "Specify an empty document { } to update all documents in the collection."

I can do this one-by-one using `db.users.update({first_name: "Joe"}, { $set: { "messages": []}})`, but this is inefficient, and not really what I want.

Comment: In the mongo shell? Sounds like an old version of MongoDB. Check `db.version()`. In older and actually current versions you just use `"multi"`: `db.users.update({first_name: "Joe"}, { $set: { "messages": []}},{ "multi": true})`. Which is basically the same thing. The only difference is `.updateMany()` ignores the option of `{ "multi": false }`

Comment: Yes, the mongo shell.  Version `3.2.13`.  I've tried connecting to both a local db, as well as to mlab.  Same error in both cases.

Comment: Run the `.update()` like I just showed you. And I was actually incorrect since the "server" version does not matter here as it's the API and therefore the "shell" version that matters. So you have an old shell by the sound of it. The `{ "multi": true }` option as explained is the universal method that has been around for a very long time.

Comment: Perfect, it worked!  However, I should note that I had to modify the query because `db.users.update({first_name: "Joe"}, { $set: { "messages": []}}, {"multi": true})` only works for documents where `first_name` is set to `Joe`.  I had to use `$regex` to hit all documents.  So, `db.users.update({first_name: {$regex: "^"}}, { $set: { "messages": []}}, {"multi": true})` worked perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: Update your mongo shell on your computer though as that is why you cannot use `.updateMany()`. It's Probably from a 2.8 or lesser version install.

Comment: One more thing: how would I update my shell to the latest version?  I'm connecting to mlab from my terminal using `mongo my_db.mlab.com:db_number/db_name -u <dbuser> -p <dbpassword>`.  It successfully connects, and when I run `db.version()`, I get `3.2.13`.

Comment: Scratch my last question.  That was a question for Google. :)

Comment: Well yes. `db.version()` returns the "server" version. It's not the shell version. Update from standard packages. And make sure your shell not running when  you update. *nix based packages will not replace the binary if its actually running

Answer (score 0):

What is the mongo version you are using?
Since "UpdateMany" has been introduced on 3.2 , make sure you are using at least that version.

Comment: Version `3.2.13`.

Comment: I am using Mongodb db version v4.0.1 and found err like : .updateMany is not a function

Comment: can you provide some code snippet?
This could happend from many different reasons.